# Total up transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, rollup

I am using SQL Server Management Studio v18.

I have an original transaction that might get adjusted either by amount or by commission%.

I want a query to total up the transactions based on ID and company and I want to keep the original transaction's `TransType`.

I have full understanding on how to aggregate columns but I don't know how to keep the TransType.

Original table:

| ID | TransType | Amount | Commission | Commission% | Company | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 555 | RE | 500 | 125 | 25% | Company A | Original Transaction |
| 555 | RT | -400 | -100 | 0% | Company A | Adjustment |
| 666 | RA | 500 | 125 | 25% | Company A | Original Transaction |
| 666 | AD | 0 | -100 | -20% | Company A | Adjustment |
| 666 | RN | 200 | 40 | 20% | Company B | Original Transaction |

Final result:

| ID | TransType | Amount | Commission | Commission% | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 555 | RE | 100 | 25 | 25% | Company A |
| 666 | RA | 500 | 25 | 5% | Company A |
| 666 | RN | 200 | 40 | 20% | Company B |

Comment: You need to point out which column(s) indicate which record is the "first" transaction.

Comment: Column "TransType" indicates the "first" transactions.
The first transaction can be any of the following type "RE, RA, RN"

Comment: @SQLROOKIE, I believe the solution query posted solves your problem query? Do check, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you the desired result set. (Solved here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aa617a6a403de147792544cdf97e9781)

```
SELECT 
summed_up.id, 
S1.transtype, 
summed_up.amount, 
summed_up.commission, 
summed_up.commission_percent, 
summed_up.company 
FROM
    (
    SELECT id, SUM(Amount) amount, SUM(Commission) commission, SUM(commission_percent) commission_percent, company
    FROM yourtable 
    GROUP BY id, company) AS summed_up
LEFT JOIN 
     (
     SELECT id, Transtype, company FROM yourtable WHERE notes = 'Original Transaction'
     ) AS S1 
     ON S1.id = summed_up.id AND S1.company = summed_up.company
```

You are essentially separating the summing operation, and the Original Transaction retrieval operation. Finally putting them together. Let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply aggregate and use a correlated subquery for the `TranType` column:

```
select ID, 
  (
    select transtype from t t2 
    where t.id = t2.id and t.company = t2.company and t2.notes = 'Original Transaction' 
  ) TransType,
  Sum(Amount) as Amount, Sum(Commission) as Commission,
  Sum([Commission%]) as [Commission%], Company
from t
group by ID, Company;
```